# PHP, is there any way to debug ftp_put()?

Tags: php

I am working on my website where is possibility to upload images. My code was working about month ago, but now stopped. Problem is (probably) somewhere in:

```
    $upload = ftp_put( $conn_id, $target_dir, $file, FTP_BINARY );
```

because it returns false. Is there any way to debug it? check what exactly is wrong and why file is not uploading?

Comment: Are you FTPing to a different server? Should be able to put files on your server without using FTP.

Comment: Check if `ftp_login` throws a warning.

Comment: Hi, no, script and file destination are on the same server. I tried also [PHP File Upload](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp), but still the same. `ftp_login` is working correctly, no warnings

Comment: You can check the logs of your FTP server - usually there is enough information for understanding the reason for the issue.

Comment: Can you please show your upload script? Maybe the file isn't even making it. I would not use FTP for this. That is an extra hoop you dont need to be jumping through.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using try catch block and printing the exception message ... this might help ..

you can also use print_r(error_get_last());

Comment: I can confirm that error_get_last() display the last error return by ftp_put. But try catch is no use